# Retrieve all forms on Webpage

Tags: phantomjs, zombie.js, casperjs

How can I retrieve all the forms that are present on the given website. Specifically the id and name of a form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply with something like that

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
 page.open('yoursitehere', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
         console.log('unable to access network');
     } else {
        var forms = page.evaluate(function(){
            //best way here     
            return document.forms;
        }); 
           //some stuff here
        console.log(forms.length);
        console.log(forms[0].name);
    }
   phantom.exit();
});
```

also, note that can't pass a non-primitive object through evaluate. You will have to do your work in the evaluate.

*Note: The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine. Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!*